# Does there exist anything more general (extension) than operator of QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematics, complex-numbers

In classical mechanics we simply have quantities which are simply scalar like momentum, energy of system but when we transit to QM it's an ad-hoc principle, at least to me, that we'll be dealing with quantities which are operator and hence commutativity can't be assumed a priori. Now I want to know if there exist anything which are kind of extension of operator since scalar in mechanics are scaled identity operator. By extension I have analogy of Real, Complex, Quaternion, Octonion in mind, the preceding thing is a substructure of the next.

Comment: Operators in quantum mechanics like momentum and energy can be viewed as a kind of measurement. There are [POVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM) in quantum mechanics, which are more general measurements than operators, but unfortunately these can't be made to correspond to physical quantities like momentum, energy, position, spin (which I think is what you're really asking about).

Answer (score 0):

All operators met in textbook QM are linear. So, if one rephrases slightly your question

*Does there exist anything more general than linear operators in QM?*,

then the answer suggests itself: non-linear operators.

As it happens, non-linear operators do play an important role in quantum field theory, where interactions can change the number of particles.

Answer (score 0):

A possible extension of operators will be operator-valued distributions.

Functions contain scalars as the constant functions, distributions are a generalization of functions, but there is a wide class of distributions whose codomains are not a field, it is an algebra of operators instead.

The context for this generalization is vector bundles over a manifold.

This [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0252960217302187?via%3Dihub) will be helpful for you.